# オーサライザーの認証ロジック（python）にてクライアントIPの取得はできないでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3, aws, lambda

オーソライザの認証ロジックをLambda（python）で実装しています。
一般的なLambda(python）利用時と同様に、ハンドラ関数にわたってくるeventパラメータからの取得を試みるのですが、取得できません。
そもそも呼び出しを受けたタイミングでeventパラメータをjson.dumps()で確認したところIPアドレスが含まれていないようです。
これは何か設定ミスがあるためなのでしょうか、それとも仕様通りでオーソライザの認証ロジックではeventパラメータからIPアドレスの取得はできないのでしょうか。

何等かの方法でクライアントIPアドレスの取得をしたいのですがよい方法ありませんでしょうか。このあたり何か情報お持ちの方教えてください。